# $.getJSON, Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: jquery, json, api

I am trying to get a value from JSON API response to map it to my HTML later on.

Part of my JSON is:

```
{
"data": {
    "nearest_area": [
        {
            "distance_miles": "13.5",
            "latitude": "34.500",
            "longitude": "33.000"
        }
    ],
    "request": [
        {
            "query": "Lat 34.68 and Lon 33.11",
            "type": "LatLon"
        }
    ],
    "weather": [
        {
            "date": "2014-12-11",
            "hourly": [
                {
                    "cloudcover": "0",
                    "humidity": "73",
                    "precipMM": "0.0",
                    "pressure": "1022",
                    "sigHeight_m": "1.5",
                    "swellDir": "257",
                    "swellHeight_m": "1.5",
                    "swellPeriod_secs": "8.4",
                    "tempC": "19",
                    "tempF": "67",
                    "time": "0",
                    "visibility": "10",
                    "waterTemp_C": "21",
                    "waterTemp_F": "70",
                    "weatherCode": "113",
                    "weatherIconUrl": [
                        {
```

My code to get it:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $('#id').html(data.weather[0].hourly[0].waterTemp_C); 
});
```

And I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

If I go `$('#id').html(data.weather.hourly[0].waterTemp_C);` I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hourly' of undefined

I am new to JSON and stuff, please help me to select it properly. I'm using http://www.worldweatheronline.com API for marine weather.

Comment: Are you sure that's the json you get back or is that the json you _expect_ to get back?

Comment: Either `data.weather` is undefined or `data.weather[0].hourly` is undefined...

Comment: You seem to expect your `data` variable to be the contents of the `data` property in your top-level object, but it's not. Your `data` variable has the contents of your top-level object, which has a `data` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a parent `"data"` property in your JSON, so your callback code should probably look like:

```
data.data.weather[0].hourly[0].waterTemp_C
│    │
│    └─ "data" property name
│
└─ callback variable name
```

Comment: Oh, it was that simple. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user27738: No problem. Sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes.